# Is it possible to have a stage in a Bamboo plan start even though the previous one has failed?

Tags: bamboo

I have a Bamboo plan configuration with several stages. Now I want to have these stages to execute in certain order, but independently of the result of the previous stage.

This seems to be impossible with Bamboo. Subsequent stages are executed only if the previous one is successful.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Really dumb that this still isn't supported within a plan.  Shouldn't have to clutter your plans to manage this simple configuration.

Answer (score 2):

> "Now I want to have these stages to execute in certain order, but
>   independently of the result of the previous stage."

The statement seems self contradicting. If you want the stages to execute in order, that implies some dependency/coupling between them. Yet you want them to execute independently of the result of the previous stage.

The they are truly independent you can configure them as independent jobs as part of one stage. These jobs(which may contain several ordered tasks) will execute independently and in parallel.

Please see the following for more details:

http://quickstart.atlassian.com/download/bamboo/get-started/bamboo-elements

Hope this helps other who stumble upon this question.

Comment: It's not contradictory.  It's the same concept as the 'finally' part of try/catch in software development

Comment: An example of where this is needed is when one stage deploys, stage two runs integration tests, and stage three removes the deployment. You want to be able to remove the deployment even if the tests failed, but the overall status should be a failure.

Answer (score 2):

Might be off-topic.

But if your only purpose is to make sure that some activities are not executed in parallel and the order does not matter, then you may try to configure these activities using Jobs.

[Bamboo documentation](https://quickstart.atlassian.com/download/bamboo/get-started/bamboo-elements) states the following:

```
 Jobs within a given Stage will run in parallel as long as there are agents available to execute them.  Otherwise, Jobs run one at a time in no particular order.
```

It means that if there is only 1 agent available, then there will be no parallel execution and jobs will be executed one by one.

Answer (score 2):

**Final stages were added to Bamboo 6.8.0 in February 2019**

As mentioned at: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-9771?focusedCommentId=1918676

The following Atlassian Community questions also asked this:

- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Creating-a-final-stage-in-Bamboo-that-is-always-run/qaq-p/543318
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-make-a-stage-run-regardless-of-previous/qaq-p/139255

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies is the way to do this. Separate your stages into separate plans. Have each plan depend on (be triggered by) the prior plan.

This doesn't give you exactly the same results, but it is the only way to do it if you need ordered stages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dependencies tab to do this, else use ant script.